# How to execute single automation across multiple business units?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I need to execute an automation on a single file drop and trigger a journey that is related to the business units. I'm trying to use a single automation in the parent BU, and based on the BU ID, I'm attempting to insert a record into a shared BU-related data extension.
My plan is then to trigger the related journey.

Please let me know if this is a good approach, or if I need to create separate automations for each BU.

I appreciate your feedback on this.

Thanks,
Prasad